# Cocoa control to render a tile map

Tags: cocoa, macos

Is there any Cocoa control that is capable of drawing tile maps with multiple layers and multiple texture sources which can also intercept touches into single tiles? Having multiple layer support is not a real requirement but an optional feature (the views could still be stacked). Hardware acceleration is not needed at all.

So far I have toyed around with `NSMatrix`, `IKImageBrowser` and `NSCollectionView` but non of them felt like a good solution for the problem. Ideally I need an control similar to the one in [Tiled.app](http://www.mapeditor.org/). Is there anything, third party or built-in, or do I have to handcraft this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that you will be hardly able to find a ready-to-use control for managing tile maps.

If I had to implement something like that on my own, I would consider using `CATiledLayer`, since this is the closest thing to a tile map control that I know of.

From [CATiledLayer Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> CATiledLayer is a subclass of CALayer providing a way to asynchronously provide tiles of the layer's content, potentially cached at multiple levels of detail.

There is a [nice sample by Bill Dudney](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example) (the author of "Core Animation for MacOS and the iPhone"). This sample could provide you a solid foundation for your own project, though it only displays one single PDF, allowing you to zoom in the area you clicked on (this requires rereading the tile at a different detail level).

Another interesting introduction can be found [here](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1857). This is more step-by-step, so you might start with this.

Finally, on [Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/) there is a nice article, although it focuses on iOS, but you may find it anyway relevant.

Comment: I will go with my own implementation using CATiledLayer, thanks for your links.

Comment: For the record: I ended up writing my own NSCollectionView like class which uses views to render the map but only creates the needed views to fill the screen: https://github.com/JustSid/JUCollectionView

Answer (score 1):

**Cocos2D supports building mac applications now**

Article on cocos2d stating this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1444

Aee here for how to do it: http://chris-fletcher.com/tag/cocos2d-os-x/

Aee here on how to use TMX tile maps with Cocos2D to build tile based maps: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:tiled_maps

This means you can use the power of Cocos2d and you will have to write much less code to get to where you want with a tile based map.

**If you don't want to use Cocos2D:**

It seems you would have to code it yourself, but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

First you can create your .TMX file using the tile editor "Tiled.app" then you would need to parse the XML using a standard xml library for Cocoa.

To lay out the tiles use a UIView for the overall container and then create a tile class that holds your tile display information and responds to clicks the tile class should extend UIView. For the tile class allow the assigning of a click delegate and assign your ViewController as the click delegate for all tiles so you can handle clicks easily with the clicked tile being passed to you.

Loop through your xml data and create and position the tiles in the overall UIView by using the tiles width/height and your tilemaps rows/columns.

I think in about a day or 2 you could have the tile map being rendered and clickable using the standard TMX format which will allow you to edit your map in "Tiled.app"

The TMX standard is covered here: https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format

Comment: Sorry, Tiled.app was just an example how the control should look like, I need a bit more than whats covered by the tmx format.

Comment: The TMX format is very robust as it covers tile maps with unlimited layers of maps. as per the creators description:

The TMX (Tile Map XML) map format used by Tiled is a flexible way to describe a tile based map. It can describe maps with any tile size, **any amount of layers**, any number of tile sets and it allows custom properties to be set on most elements. Beside tile layers, it can also contain groups of objects that can be placed freely.

Comment: @zachzum: Yes, I know the format hence I implemented it not too long ago, but I need something a bit more custom.

Comment: I understand. It's too bad I couldn't help.

Comment: I accepted the CATiledLayer approach because it is more straightforward than using Cocos2d for the rendering. Cocos2d is just too much overkill for the project, but thanks for bringing my attention to the mac port, I wasn't aware of that until today!

Answer (score -2):

[route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) might fit the bill.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a Mac OS X control.

Comment: You didn't even look at the source code did you.. :( More to the point, that library provides fairly generic code for exactly what you're wanting.. It's not limited to iOS. You can lead the horse to water I guess..

Comment: I did look into the code. But all I could find was iOS related stuff and targets, nothing OS X related. But I will look again.

Comment: I still can't find any OS X related stuff, but lots of iOS exclusive stuff. Am I missing something?